# UITapGesture on UITableView not being called

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to handle some operation when user tap on a `UITextField` inside `UItableView` with following code but the `tapDetected:` code is not being called.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    UITextField *txtComment=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10,cell.contentView.frame.size.width-30 , 30)];
    [txtComment setText:NSLocalizedString(@"Comment Here", nil)];
    [txtComment setFont:mediumFont];
    [txtComment setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [txtComment setTag:newCommentTag];
    txtComment.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    txtComment.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor lightGrayColor]CGColor];
    txtComment.layer.borderWidth= 0.3f;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap =
            [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                       initWithTarget:self
                       action:@selector(tapDetected:)];
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [txtComment addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:txtComment];


- (IBAction)tapDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:spAddNewCommentNotification object:nil];
}
```

Comment: set frame of your cell

Comment: Why you dont use the didselectrow method

Comment: add this line **tap.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;** and check.

Comment: Did you tried the above line?

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass your own UITableViewCell and put the touch detection inside.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you touch that time `UITableViewdidSelect` delegate method is called. So please follow this code :

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
 {
    if ([touch.view isDescendantOfView:cell])
    {
       return NO;
    }   
    return YES;
 }
```

Try this one. I think this can help you :)